# How to build an ATL project properly?

Tags: c++, atl

For the lack of the documentation on the Internet about this technologie, can someone please just explain the architecture of an ATL project (Service EXE) ?

And, give a full example of the main methods defined by Microsoft able to be written xxx.cpp item ?

An example of response to the second question:

```
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, 
                                LPTSTR /*lpCmdLine*/, int nShowCmd)
{
    return _AtlModule.WinMain(nShowCmd);
}

void CATLProject6Module::ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv)
{
    // I can do this this and this

    CAtlServiceModuleT<CATLProject6Module, 100>::ServiceMain(dwArgc, lpszArgv);
}

//Run method()...

//Handler method()...

//...
```

This topic may help anyone interested in developing his first `Active Template Library` application (Service EXE) !

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: ATL service project is basically a variant/extension of local COM server (.EXE) which can be switched to run as service. That's it, there are no special methods. Internals of implementation are available to you with source code.

Comment: @RomanR., then I just need to learn how to build COM server (.EXE) to learn how to build ATL service project ? Have you any tutorial or samples in mind, please ?